# PHP regex matching multiple entries?

Tags: php, regex, file

I'm parsing a log file line by line.

I want to match on the following :

```
"GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200
"GET /manager HTTP/1.1" 200
"GET /manager HTTP/1.1" 401
"GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 401
```

Currently I'm assigning each of these options to it's own variable, then doing :

```
if (strpos($line,$a) || strpos($line,$b) || strpos($line,$c) || strpos($line,$d)) 
    {
    }
```

if there a better way ?
thanks

Comment: What do you want to match? Your question is not clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regular expression will match all four variations:

```
^"GET /manager/? HTTP/1\.1" (200|401)$
```

You will also have to escape the slashes with a backslash unless you use another character as the delimiter.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I've tried, but it returns no results:
`if (preg_match('^"GET \/manager\/? HTTP\/1\.1" (200|401)$^', $line)) `

Comment: The syntax is wrong. Use either `/^`...`$/`, or `~^`...`$~` and unescape the slashes.

Comment: sorry not getting this :  `if (preg_match('~^"GET /manager/? HTTP/1\.1" (200|401)$~',$line))`

Comment: That should work. If it doesn't then perhaps `$line` contains other characters? Trailing whitespace maybe?

Comment: `$line` does contain other entries.. I'm trying to match any of those 4 values anywhere within `$line`

Comment: In that case remove the `^` and `$` from the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
$str = '
"GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200
"GET /manager HTTP/1.1" 200
"GET /manager HTTP/1.1" 401
"GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 401
';

preg_match_all('#^\s*("GET\s+/manager/?\s+HTTP/1\.1"\s+(?:200|401)+)#im', $str, $match);
print_r($match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex `(GET|POST)\s+(.*)\s+(HTTP.*)\s+(\d{3})` This will give you `["GET", "/manager/", "HTTP/1.1", "401"]`

Updated code:

```
$logStr = '"GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 200
"GET /manager HTTP/1.1" 200
"GET /manager HTTP/1.1" 401
"GET /manager/ HTTP/1.1" 401
';
echo $logStr;
preg_match('/(GET|POST)\s+(.*)\s+(HTTP.*)\s+(\d{3})/', $logStr, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```